# Unable to update a varaibale using useState hook after a component rerender

Tags: reactjs, redux

I want to display a snackBar whenever a user signIn successfully or something wrong was happen.
MyComponent.jsx:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import SnackBar from '../../components/SnackBar';
import SignInForm from './SignInForm';

const SingInContainer = ({ message, variant}) => {
    const [open, setSnackBarState] = useState(!!variant);

    const handleClose = () => {
        setSnackBarState(false)

      };

    return (
        <div>
        <SnackBar
            open={open}
            handleClose={handleClose}
            variant={variant}
            message={message}
            />
        <SignInForm/>
        </div>
    )
}

SingInContainer.propTypes = {
    variant: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    message: PropTypes.string.isRequired
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    const {variant, message } = state.snackBar;

    return {
        variant,
        message
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(SingInContainer);
```

The `open` prop always set to false, however `variant` is updated after the component was rerenderd by `connect` HOC. I didn't found what's my mistake?

Comment: You are never invoking `handleClose` by writing `() => handleClose`. Try `() => handleClose()` instead. It also looks like you may want to pass in the event and a reason as well. `(e) => handleClose(e, 'something')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parameter to useState is only used once on initial update, if you want to perform an update to state when the variant prop is updated you can use useEffect hook

```
const SingInContainer = ({ message, variant}) => {
    const [open, setSnackBarState] = useState(!!variant);
    useEffect(() => {
       setSnackBarState(!!variant);
    }, [variant])
    const handleClose = () => {
        setSnackBarState(false)

      };

    return (
        <div>
        <SnackBar
            open={open}
            handleClose={handleClose}
            variant={variant}
            message={message}
            />
        <SignInForm/>
        </div>
    )
}
```